# PHP Sessions "SELECT * from users where username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";

Tags: php

I have set up a login script which seems to work fine

The problem im having is the code below is not working:

```
session_start(); 

$sql = "SELECT * from users where username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
    echo "<tr><td>$row[username]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[email]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[id]</td>";
}
```

if i output

```
session_start(); 
Print_r ($_SESSION);
```

I get

```
Array ( [user] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => craig [email] => craig@craig.com ) )
```

Comment: are you connected to the db?

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Not working... how? Add details of errors, or what you expect to happen...

Comment: Don't forget the possible nasty SQL injection vuln. I haven't coded in PHP in a while but last I remember, it was recommended to use PDO.

Comment: "Not working" is never a good problem description

Comment: why you are executing query if all the user data in session..

Answer (score 9):

You need to access the `username` key in the `user` part of the array. As such:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users where username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username'] ."'";
```

Otherwise you would only trying to access the Array, holding all the id, username and email keys.
And as pointed out, NEVER do this, due to the SQL-injection.

You ought to use PDO instead. If your webserver doesn't support it, at least escape your strings with mysql_real_escape_string() before:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users where username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['username']) ."'";
```

Comment: Thanks Eric your a star

Comment: @Craig You're welcome. And for future use, please mark this as the "Correct Answer", so people with similar problem can relate to it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from users where username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'";
```

Comment: My username is `PeeHaa' or 1=1--`.